# Jquery show or hide elements with an event

Tags: jquery

I'm starting with jquery and I have a question about some practice I'm doing.

I have this html code:

```
<div id="caja">
  <div id="botones">
      <button class="content1">1</button>
      <button class="content2">2</button>
      <button class="content3">3</button>
      <button class="content4">4</button>
  </div>
  <div id="contenidos">
      <p class="content1">Contenido 1</p>
      <p class="content2">Contenido 2</p>
      <p class="content3">Contenido 3</p>
      <p class="content4">Contenido 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this jquery code:

```
$('#contenidos').find('p').hide();

$('#botones').find('button').on('click' , function(){
    var claseb = $(this).attr('class');

  $(this).closest('#contenidos').find('p' , function(){
    $(this).attr('class').not(claseb).hide();
    $(this).hasClass(claseb).show();
  });


});
```

My intention is when I click on any button I want only show the content appropriate to this button and hide the others. I don't know where is the fail in the jquery code.

There is jsfiddle: [code](https://jsfiddle.net/srfubu/zwrt2e4b/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can select `p` by class of `button` that is clicked and show that `p` and hide siblings like this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zwrt2e4b/1/)

```js
$('#contenidos p').hide();

$('#botones button').on('click', function() {
  var claseb = $(this).attr('class');
  $('#contenidos .' + claseb).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The part that fails is `$(this).closest('#contenidos')`.

`.closest()` traverses up the DOM looking for matches, and since the event is being triggered on a click from a button that's a child of a previous sibling, `.closest()` won't find it.

Instead use:

```
$('#botones button').on('click' , function(){
  var claseb = $(this).attr('class');
  $('#contenidos p').hide();
  $('#contenidos p.'+claseb).show();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zwrt2e4b/3/)**

Comment: Thx but just as a side note,  `find()` part in OP's code is failing too, there is no callback for this (sync) method

Comment: @A.Wolff - yes I see what you mean. You're obviously correct, and I didn't keep that part of my answer.

Comment: @A.Wolff - I don't know if the find would even be executed since the .closest() wouldn't succeed. But good for pointing out the error in that find syntax. 